# How to make mobile SMS send system?

Tags: sms, sms-gateway

I Have a small online shopping website, i want to send my customers to the latest deals information, how can i code this system give me a example.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a hardware phone attached to the server or do you want to use an external service?

Comment: Need a external service

Comment: Out of curiosity, what language are you using?

Comment: thanks for the comment,Im using PHP

Comment: No worries, feel free to check out my updated answer for sample code on sending an SMS using Nexmo's SMS API in PHP! Happy coding!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I suggest using a SMS Gateway API, as I see you are trying to implement an external service.

Nexmo, where I work, has an SMS API that is easy to use, reliable, and provides security when reaching out to users.

You can reach users in over 200 countries with one simple HTTP call.

Here is a [link](https://docs.nexmo.com/index.php/sms-api) to the docs for the SMS API

EDIT: I saw your comment about using PHP @Nova... look below for sample code which will allow you to send your first SMS using Nexmo's SMS API in PHP. 
*(You will receive an API Key & API Secret after signing up for a Nexmo trial account)*

```
<?php
$url = 'https://rest.nexmo.com/sms/json?' . http_build_query([
    'api_key' => API_KEY,
    'api_secret' => API_SECRET,
    'to' => YOUR_NUMBER,
    'from' => NEXMO_NUMBER,
    'text' => 'Hello from Nexmo'
]);

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help , :)